# Powershell - Continue a script after exiting an application

Tags: powershell

I'm quite new to Powershell.
To be able to run a certain program I need to disable a device.
This was not to hard, I created the following:

```
$DeviceID = (Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*Devicename*").InstanceId
Disable-PnpDevice "$DeviceID" -Confirm:$false
& 'path\file.exe'
```

So far so good. But now I want to Enable the device after I exit the program.
How do I make the script see that I end the program?

Answer (score 0):

Try trapping the result:

```
& 'path\file.exe' 2>&1
```

Then test for the exit code which should be held in the environment variable

```
$LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: I don't get an exit code, but persuing some other options I found while exploring this one.
Thanks for getting me back on track.